# proper jquery syntax for descendant of dom element stored as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, syntax

Given  a div with a child div

```
<div class='parent'>
<div class = 'child>
</div>
</div>
```

I can access the child with jQuery using ($(div.parent div.child)

But what if I have defined parent as
    $parent=$("div.parent");

What is the syntax for accessing the child div of $parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
 var $parent = $("div.parent");

   $parent.children('.child');
```

Comment: Just a note: `children` will only look for direct children. To include all descendants (which would be the strict equivalent of OP's selector), use `find` instead.